How to make a dashed line on matplotlib fill entire domain

This is rather nitpicky, and I hope I'm describing this well. You see that leftmost black dashed tick on the number line? I want it to be a dashed line (which it successfully is.) But I also want it to be as long as all of the solid lines to the right of it. I'm noticing that the plotting function refuses to do this. I made a solid orange line underneath it to show the full range that the dashed line should fill. For some reason, it absolutely refuses to fill the entire region from the bottom of the orange line to the top of the orange line. Any idea why this might be?
Here's the line of code where I plot the dashed line and orange line, respectively. Notice that they are not the same length. The dashed line will not take up the entire length of the orange line.
def DrawLine(xCenter, yCenter, tickHeight, center = True):
    x = xCenter * np.ones(2)
    y = linspace(yCenter, yCenter + tickHeight, num = 2)
    if (center):
        y = y - (tickHeight / 2.)
    return (x, y)
xAxis = [0., 0.03125, 0.0625, 0.09375, 0.125, 0.15625]
yAxis = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
height = 0.09226038271880456
for (xi, yi) in zip(xAxis, yAxis):
    (xs, ys) = DrawLine(xi, yi, height)
    ax.plot(xs, ys, color = '#ff7f0e', zorder = 0, linewidth = 1.5)
    ax.plot(xs, ys, color = 'k', zorder = 2, linewidth = 1.5, linestyle = '--')


It would appear that the pattern of ticks starts a few pixels in - you'd need some way to shift the pattern, so that it goes from .---.-- to -.---.- or something along those lines. I think you could save yourself an awful lot of trouble for very little gain if you didn't go down that rabbit-hole and just made the tick a solid line instead of dashed. Does a dashed tick even make sense to you? Something like set_dashes may be able to allow you to change the offset - but if that's reliable, I don't know

An alternate solution, if this is just a one-off you need to get perfect, is to not draw the dash, but instead just code a dashed line object where it should appear, which may give you more control over its appearance. A hack, but for a one-off that may save you hours of fidgeting for something nobody appreciates anyway.

I was afraid that would be the case. The thing is, it seems to cut off some clearance from the top and the bottom for some reason.

What bothers me most is the top part. It shortens the tick for some reason. I'd be fine with the bottom missing part if not for the missing part at the top.

I would try experimenting with the capstyle keywords: solid_capstyle defaults to "projecting" whereas dashed_capstyle defaults to "butt".

Capstyle examples: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/capstyle.html

Here is a small example on how to customize the dashed lines capstyles and dashes lengths, so one configuration might fit your needs, see "Customizing dashed line styles"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1, 2]
lw = 10
capstyles = ["butt", "round", "projecting"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Classic lines
y = 0
for capstyle in capstyles:
    y += 0.1
    ax.plot(xs, [y, y], ls="-", lw=lw, solid_capstyle=capstyle)
    ax.annotate(f"'-', {capstyle}", (2.1, y), va="center")

# Dashed lines [2, 3]
y += 0.1
for capstyle in capstyles:
    y += 0.1
    ax.plot(xs, [y, y], ls="--", lw=lw, dash_capstyle=capstyle, dashes=[2, 3])
    ax.annotate(f"'--', {capstyle}, [2, 3]", (2.1, y), va="center")

# Dashed lines [2, 2]
y += 0.1
for capstyle in capstyles:
    y += 0.1
    ax.plot(xs, [y, y], ls="--", lw=lw, dash_capstyle=capstyle, dashes=[2, 2])
    ax.annotate(f"'--', {capstyle}, [2, 2]", (2.1, y), va="center")

# Vertical lines at xs boundaries
ax.axvline(xs[0], color="black", lw=1)
ax.axvline(xs[1], color="black", lw=1)

ax.set_xlim(0, 3)
fig.show()



You could use a stem plot :
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))

ax.plot(x[h:], y[h:], "-C0")
ax.plot(x[: h + 1], y[: h + 1], "--C0")
ax.stem(x[h], y[h], linefmt="C2", basefmt="w")
ax.stem(x[h_vals], y[h_vals], linefmt="C2:", basefmt="w")
ax.plot(1-0.05, 0, ">k",transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
ax.hlines(0, x[h_vals[0]], x[h], color="k", lw=2, ls="--")
ax.hlines(0, x[h], xmax, color="k", lw=2, ls="-")

fprop = dict(math_fontfamily="cm", ha="center", fontsize=14)

for i, ix in enumerate(x[h_vals], -1):
    ax.vlines(ix, -2.5, 2.5, color="k", lw=2, linestyle="-")
    ax.text(ix + 0.8, -5, latex(r"\Delta{x}", i), **fprop)
    ax.text(ix, -7, latex("x", i), **fprop)

for i, (ix, iy) in enumerate(zip(x[h_vals][1:], y[h_vals][1:]), -1):
    ax.hlines(iy - 2, ix - np.diff(x[h_vals])[0], ix, color="r", lw=2, ls="-")
    ax.text(ix - .5, iy - 3, latex(r"\langle{{R_2}}\rangle", i), **fprop)

ax.axis("off");


Setup :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 15, 100)
y = -x  * (x - 15)
xmin, xmax = .5, 9
y[(x < xmin) | (x > xmax)] = np.nan

# h as x-indices (not x-values)
h = 25
h_step = 10
h_vals = np.arange(h-h_step, 50, h_step)

def latex(prefix, i):
    return r"${}_{{h{:+}}}$".format(prefix, i).replace("+0", "")

